# total variation of quadratic variation as limit in probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

If $X_t, Y_t$ ,  $t\geq 0$ are real valued continuous local martingales, the quadratic variation at time t ,$[X,Y]_t$, is the limit in probability $$\lim_{\Vert P\Vert \to 0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left( X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}}\right)\left(Y_{t_k}-Y_{t_{k-1}}\right).$$
where P are partitions of [0,t] whose mesh goes to 0.  This made me wonder if $$\lim_{\Vert P\Vert \to 0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\big |\left( X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}}\right)\left(Y_{t_k}-Y_{t_{k-1}}\right)\big |$$ converges in probability to the total variation of $[X,Y]$, i.e. $$\int_0^t|d[X,Y]|.$$